# How would I pass a template member function by pointer to another member function?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I'd like to be able to pass in maps of widget types and their actions along with a reference to the template member function I've shown in the example below such that I'm able to handle the binding in a simple data driven loop. I've made a few attempts, but can't figure out how I would pass the template function as a function pointer without the arguments.

(I'm also open to other suggestions on how one might approach this in c++)

```
void AVRPawn::SetupPlayerInputComponent(UInputComponent* PlayerInputComponent) {

  Super::SetupPlayerInputComponent(PlayerInputComponent);

  PlayerInputComponent->BindAction(LP_Constant::TRIGGER_PRESS_RIGHT_ACTION, IE_Pressed, this, &AVRPawn::TriggerPressed<IE_Pressed, ESide::Right>);
  PlayerInputComponent->BindAction(LP_Constant::TRIGGER_PRESS_RIGHT_ACTION, IE_Released, this, &AVRPawn::TriggerPressed<IE_Released, ESide::Right>);
  PlayerInputComponent->BindAction(LP_Constant::TRIGGER_PRESS_LEFT_ACTION, IE_Pressed, this, &AVRPawn::TriggerPressed<IE_Pressed, ESide::Left>);
  PlayerInputComponent->BindAction(LP_Constant::TRIGGER_PRESS_LEFT_ACTION, IE_Released, this, &AVRPawn::TriggerPressed<IE_Released, ESide::Left>);
}
```

In javascript, I would create a simple higher order function to enclose the differing data, but I'm having a very hard time finding an eloquent way to do this in c++.

Comment: Are you getting a compiler error?  Add it to your question.

Comment: Not at the moment, because I've reverted everything to this spaghetti code.  But I remember one of them involving decltype ( * ) could not be converted to decltype (AVRPawn:: *). I'm experimenting with std::function right now to see if that might help me compose the callback.

Comment: I would think it will.  `IE_Pressed` and `ESide::Right` (to pick a specific example) look to me like they should be parameters to be passed to the delegate _when it is called_, rather than template parameters.

Comment: Yeah, that's the goal, but I can't seem to pre-bind the arguments to my callback without getting type errors regarding the delegate signature.

Comment: Paul's suggestion is that the `TriggerPressed` function should not be a template at all. That is, if right now it can be called as `pawn.TriggerPressed<IE_Pressed, ESide::Right>(arg1, arg2);`, change it so it can be called as `pawn.TriggerPressed(IE_Pressed, ESide::Right, arg1, arg2);`  Is there any reason this wouldn't work?  Because any framework to make the member template easier to pass will probably need a bunch of evil macro magic.

Comment: Yeah the problem is that there are no reasonable delegate signatures, by default, that allow you to to take in any reasonable parameters, but I did end up finding a way to manually bind a lambda callback.

Answer (score 2):

So my solution to this ended up being non-template based. It was a limitation of the UE4 framework, or more accurately, my lack of in depth knowledge of it.  I ended up coming across a way to bind a lambda callback which I pass the Action and Event to.

```
void AVRPawn::BindPressableInput(UInputComponent* InputComponent) {
  for (auto const& Controller : MotionControllers) {
    for (auto const& Action : Controller->GetInputActions()) {
      for (auto const& Event : PressAndReleaseEvents) {
        FInputActionBinding Binding(Action, Event);
        Binding.ActionDelegate.GetDelegateForManualSet().BindLambda([=, &Controller]() {
          Controller->HandleInputEvent(Action, Event);
        });
        InputComponent->AddActionBinding(Binding);
      }
    }
  }
}

void AVRPawn::SetupPlayerInputComponent(UInputComponent* InputComponent) {
  Super::SetupPlayerInputComponent(InputComponent);
  BindPressableInput(InputComponent);
}
```